# Jmock with reflection

Tags: java, reflection, jmock

I have a requirement where i need to mock the com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker and return null when accessing printWarningsIfRequired in that class. Since Deploy.jar is not in my build path, i couldnt directly mock it up. I'm looking at a way to implement it using Java reflection API.  but i'm not sure how to invoke the mock method with the Class argument.
            method.invoke(null, new Class[]{claz1}); is failing with NP exception.

Here is the code

```
    Mockery context ;
    final Class<?> claz1;
    try {
     Class   mclaz = Class.forName("org.jmock.Mockery");
        context =   (Mockery) mclaz.newInstance();

        claz1 = Class.forName("com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker");
        final Method method = mclaz.getDeclaredMethod("mock",
                new Class[]{Class.class} ); 


        method.invoke(null, new Class[]{claz1});
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stated goal in to use reflection but if I had to do this i'd just create a test-only jar that includes an interface that mimics the com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker class.  Then use jmock to mock the stand-in.

I've taken this approach before when I couldn't include the actual class in my testing setup like you and it works like a champ.  Just be sure that your stand-in doesn't make it to the runtime classpath and remains in test scope only.

Comment: Make sure you're capitalizing your sentences properly.  This is a professional website; we expect answers to have proper capitalization, punctuation and spelling.  If English is your second language, put your answers through a spelling and grammar checker before posting them.